# Capacity Provisioning for Server Farms Markov Chain Queues

Tags: server, queue, provisioning, markov-chains, capacity

Suppose we are using an M/M/N model, how many servers would we need to keep the probability of an arriving job to wait to be less than 0.2. Given that jobs arrive at a rate of 400/second, and the processing times are exponentially distributed with a mean of 1 second.

So I used Erlang's C-formula:

```
P[queueing] = (1/c!)*(lambda/mu)^(c)*(1/(1-rho))*pi_o
```

And got an answer of 4 servers, however when I used the model they showed in the textbook:

```
rho < 1 -> (lambda)/(k*mu) -> k > lambda/mu
```

I get k = 400 servers. I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808038/capacity-provisioning-for-server-farms?

Comment: @JimMischel although the given information such as arrival rate and processing times are the same, this one involves an M/M/N model, while the link question involves N M/M/1 parallel queues